# How to store and use rules as string in neo4j node property

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```
create (a:Class {name:'A'})-[:subClassOf]->(b:Class {name:'B'}) 
create (b)-[:subClassOf]->(c:Class {name:'C'}) 
create (rule:Rule {name:'Rule1',
       condition:'exists( (a:Class)-[:subClassOf]->(b:Class) ) AND exists(  (b:Class)-[:subClassOf]->(c:Class) )', 
       action:'create (a)-[:subClassOf]->(c)'})
```

I try to save the rule data as a string in the node properties, not in the backend program, and then create a query, read the conditions in the rule, and if it returns true, execute the action, for example:
if exists any A-[:subClassOf]->B AND B-[:subClassOf]->C, then create A-[:subClassOf]->C.

I wrote a query like follows:

```
MATCH (rule:Rule)
WHERE rule.name = 'Rule1'
WITH rule, toBoolean(rule.condition) AS condition
WHERE condition
CALL apoc.cypher.run(rule.action) YIELD value
RETURN value
```

But this query doesn't seem to return any results, how should I do it correctly?   Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

I would lean towards using something like `CALL apoc.cypher.run(rule.condition,{}) YIELD value as condition` for running and evaluating your condition. The issue with your current condition syntax is that it isn't valid Cypher.

Then you could use something like `CALL apoc.do.when()` to run the action Cypher based on value of condition. However, this means you would need to re-select the condition data again because running a generic `create (a)-[:subClassOf]->(c)` will do this across the whole data set, rather than only where (a)-->(b)-->(c). So I'd recommend updating the action Cypher to select the subset of data and create the new relationship.

It would look something like this:

```
create (a:Class {name:'A'})-[:subClassOf]->(b:Class {name:'B'}) 
create (b)-[:subClassOf]->(c:Class {name:'C'}) 
create (rule:Rule {name:'Rule1',
       condition:'RETURN exists((:Class)-[:subClassOf]->(:Class)-[:subClassOf]->(:Class)) AS test', 
       action:'MATCH (a:Class)-[:subClassOf]->(b:Class)-[:subClassOf]->(c:Class) MERGE (a)-[r:subClassOf]->(c)'})

MATCH (rule:Rule {name: 'Rule1'})
CALL apoc.cypher.run(rule.condition,{}) YIELD value
WITH rule, value.test as condition
CALL apoc.do.when(condition, "CALL apoc.cypher.runSchema(rule.action,{}) YIELD value RETURN value", "RETURN 'no action taken'", {rule:rule}) YIELD value
RETURN value;
```